# Application Configuration Properties on Payara (how to read them)

Tags: java, properties, application-server, payara

I would like to use Application Configuration Properties that you can configure using the user interface of payara (for example):

[image: Application Configuration Properties]

My question is: how can I access these values on java code side? Through annotation? Through some sort of context instance maybe? Is it even possible?

I naively tried with System.getProperty with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way.
An alternative would be to use system properties along with variable substitution via ${} syntax or environment variable via ${ENV.XXX}